# SQL - Using specific 'order by' command

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query;

```
select *
from
(
    Select distinct Siparisler.IsEmriNo,MakinelerVeParcalar.Ozellik,DurumBilgisi.ID
    from Siparisler,MakinelerVeParcalar,DurumBilgisi Where DurumBilgisi.ID = MakinelerVeParcalar.ID and Siparisler.IsEmriNo = MakinelerVeParcalar.IsEmriNo
) x
order by
    case when IsEmriNo LIKE '%OC%' then 0
         when IsEmriNo LIKE '%SB%' then 1
         when IsEmriNo LIKE '%MR%' then 2 end,
    IsEmriNo
```

My output;

```
IsEmriNo    Ozellik    ID
--------    -------    --
OC19U001    Ozel       1
OC19U002    Yok        2
OC19U003    Yok        3
SB19U001    Yok        4
SB19U002    Yok        5
MR19U001    Yok        6
MR19U002    Yok        7
MR19U003    Yok        8
```

But I want;

```
IsEmriNo    Ozellik    ID
--------    -------    --
OC19U003    Yok        3
OC19U002    Yok        2
OC19U001    Ozel       1
SB19U003    Yok        5
SB19U002    Yok        4
MR19U003    Yok        8
MR19U002    Yok        7
MR19U001    Yok        6
```

I want ordering with last 3 char and ordering first 2 char with 'case' command.I cant use left-right command with case.Please help me... Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.  If I understand correctly, you want to order by the minimum id based on the first five characters (or perhaps the first two -- it is not clear).  Then by the `id` descending.

You can do this using window functions:

```
order by min(id) over (partition by left(IsEmriNo, 5)),
         id desc
```

If you want to order by the last two characters in `IsEmriNo`:

```
order by min(id) over (partition by left(IsEmriNo, 5)),
         right(IsEmriNo, 2) desc
```

Comment: ID is not important.It is random.I need last 3 char for descending

Comment: @HasanKaanTURAN . . . I adjusted the answer.

Comment: I have MR19V003. But ordering; MR19U003,MR19U002,MR19U001,MR19V003... Why ? I want ; MR19U003,MR19V003,MR19U002,MR19U001

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you just order descending on the second level of your current sort, keeping the rest the same:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%OC%' THEN 0
         WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%SB%' THEN 1
         WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%MR%' THEN 2 END,
    IsEmriNo DESC;
```

You might in fact want to just `id DESC` instead, but perhaps it is coincidence that the `id` and `IsEmriNo` columns happen to order the same way.

Comment: ID is random.Not important for me

Answer (score 0):

Using `SUBSTRING()` with `PATINDEX()` in `ORDER BY` will help:

```
SELECT IsEmriNo, Ozellik, ID
FROM TableName 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(IsEmriNo, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', IsEmriNo) - 1) DESC, 
         SUBSTRING(IsEmriNo, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', IsEmriNo), LEN(IsEmriNo)) ASC
```

Comment: Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.