# SQL - Ordering with part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for repost. But I need. I have 8 length string and my query;

```
select distinct Siparisler.IsEmriNo, MakinelerVeParcalar.Ozellik, DurumBilgisi.ID 
from Siparisler,
     MakinelerVeParcalar,
     DurumBilgisi 
where DurumBilgisi.ID = MakinelerVeParcalar.ID
  and Siparisler.IsEmriNo = MakinelerVeParcalar.IsEmriNo
```

and my IsEmriNo list;

```
MR18U001
MR18U002
MR18V001
MR19U003
MR19V002
MR19V001
OC19U002
OC18V005
OC18U007
SB18U010
SB18V005
SB19U028
```

And I want

```
MR19U003
MR19V002
MR19V001
SB19U028
OC19U002
MR18U002
MR18U001
MR18V001
SB18U010
SB18V005
OC18U007
OC18V005
```

First ordering: 
3rd and 4th character (Descending 19,18,17 ...)

Second ordering: 
1st and 2nd character (Ascending MR,SB,OC ... -> specific for me)

Third ordering:
Last 3 character (Descending 030,029,028 ... 001)

Not duplicate with my old post.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Using specific 'order by' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492677/sql-using-specific-order-by-command)

Comment: No it isnt.Please look details

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `order by` will work in your scenario:

```
order by substring(IsEmriNo, 3, 2) desc,
         CASE WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%MR%' THEN 0
              WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%SB%' THEN 1
              WHEN IsEmriNo LIKE '%OC%' THEN 2
             END,
         right(IsEmriNo, 3) desc
```